# Is it possible to use DOCPROPERTY in a Quick Part Formula? (Word 2007)

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

Is it possible to use a Custom Document Property in a Quick Parts formula in Word 2007?

Custom Property is a Date and formula should calculate Custom Property Date + 1 for each row in a table

Have tried the following to initially display a Custom Property in a formula without success:

```
={DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty"}
=DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty"
{DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty"}
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Word's field functions are funny things ;-).
Only add 1 to the days of a date is "simple":

```
{ QUOTE "{ DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty" \@ "yyyy-MM-" }{ = { DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty" \@ "dd" } + 1 }" \@ "yyyy-MM-dd" }
```

But this is not the solution. If CustomProperty is 2014-12-31, then it "computes" 2014-12-32.

The complete solution is shown here http://www.addbalance.com/word/datefields2.htm.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: The above proposed solution did not work, unfortunately. Also tried several combinations of the above, including {QUOTE "{ DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty"}. Also, manually updated the field each time and no data displayed.

Comment: Format mentioned in the above link did not work either, unfortunately.

{= { DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty"}}

Comment: {= { DOCPROPERTY "CustomProperty"}} can't work because a formula term { = term } must be numeric. Thats why i had used only the day part in the formula in my example.